# Avoid characters at the beginning and at the end of text using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I want to transform the next examples: #39 #401 #102 into a link. These are inside a big text. Therefore I try to detect them through regular expressions. I made the following pattern:

```
pattern_issue = '#[0-9]*'
```

However, since it has been shown into the web after the escape, this:

```
I'm your father
```

results in:

```
I&#39;m your father
```

The error is because my preprocessing function. I want to modify my regex pattern to avoid those like:

```
pattern_issue = '[^&][#][0-9]*[^;]'
```

So in that way "this the issue #37" is transformed to a link, but "I &# 39; m your father" not, but no succeed!

Hope you can help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `(?<!&)#[0-9]+(?!;)\b`?

Comment: What's the function of the \b? I removed it and it works? @stribizhev

Comment: `\b` denotes a word boundary. Essentially any white space, beginning or end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<!&)#[0-9]+(?!;)
```

The negative look-behind `(?<!&)` makes sure there is no `&` before `#` and the negative look-ahead makes sure there is no `;` after the digits.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qJ6jD1/4)

In my intial comment, I used the same pattern with `\b` at the end to force the match at the end word boundary (just to make sure that the last digit matched is followed with a non-word character). So, `(?<!&)#[0-9]+(?!;)\b` is supposed to work if you plan to ignore `#100;`-like entities.